# Problem understanding this specific AM-GM inequality proof

Tags: inequality

This is taken from Secrets in Inequalities by Pham Kim Hung

So, this part of the proof involves proving that $f(n)$ implies $f(n-1)$. So we define a term as $a_n = \frac{s}{n-1}$. We define $s = a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_{n-1}$

The next step says that via the inductive hypothesis, we get
$s + \frac{s}{n-1} \ge n \sqrt[n]{\frac{a_1a_2...a_n \cdot s}{n-1}} \rightarrow s \ge (n-1)\sqrt[n-1]{a_1a_2...a_{n-1}}$.

However, I don't see the proof went from $s + \frac{s}{n-1} \ge n \sqrt[n]{\frac{a_1a_2...a_n \cdot s}{n-1}} \rightarrow s \ge (n-1)\sqrt[n-1]{a_1a_2...a_{n-1}}$

Can someone help me out? I don't get how the lefthand side implies the right right side. The best I could see was that
$(n-1)s + s \ge n(n-1) \sqrt[n]{\frac{a_1a_2...a_n \cdot s}{n-1}} \rightarrow s \ge (n-1) \sqrt[n]{\frac{a_1a_2...a_n \cdot s}{n-1}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the AM-GM inequality holds for $n$ terms, apply it to
$$a_1,\,a_2,\ldots,\,a_{n-1},\,\frac s{n-1}$$
to get
$$s + \frac{s}{n-1} \ge n \sqrt[n]{a_1a_2...a_{n-1}\frac{s}{n-1}}\ .$$
(note that there is an error in your first inequality, it should not contain $a_n$.)  Bring the LHS to a common denominator, cancel $n$, split the RHS to get
$$\frac{s}{n-1} \ge\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2...a_{n-1}}\sqrt[n]{\frac{s}{n-1}}\ .$$
Bring the second term on the RHS back to the left:
$$\Bigl(\frac{s}{n-1}\Bigr)^{\frac{n-1}n}\ge\sqrt[n]{a_1a_2...a_{n-1}}\ .$$
Take each side to the power $\frac n{n-1}$ and you are done.